# Why is a blank string greater than 0 in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Why does

```
="" > 0
```

Evaluate to TRUE?

And how can I input a value that would evaluate to FALSE that is *not* a number?

Comment: Why? Only the designers of Sheets spec would be able to say for sure, but my guess is they decided to make any string greater than any number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I input a value that would evaluate to FALSE that is not a
>   number?

Use [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en).

> **Syntax**
>   ISNUMBER(value)
>
> value - The value to be verified as a number.
>
> *ISNUMBER returns TRUE if this is a number or a reference to a cell containing a numeric value and FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by 1 and then evaluate >0.

This may help anyone who wants to have zeroes in the list but still want to evaluate if greater than zero.